# How do I send files via jQuery AJAX with multiple parameter to an MVC controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

`enter code here`I have read several answers about this question, but no one works.

I have the following code but my `HttpPostedFileBase[]` array is always null.
The Other parameters has the right value, but the `HttpPostedFileBase[]` is always null.

What am i missing??

```
$('#myFile').on('change', function (e) {                                                                      
    var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;                                                                    

    archivosProcesar = new FormData();                                                                        

    for (var i = 0; i <= e.target.files.length -1; i++) {                                                     
        archivosProcesar.append(i, e.target.files[i]);                                                        
    }                                                                                                         
});                                                                                                           

function aplicarFragmentacion() {                                                                             
    var ids = obtenerAfiliadosSeleccionados();                                                                
    var data = {                                                                                              
        fragmento1: parseInt($('#fragmento1').val()),                                                         
        fragmento2: parseInt($('#fragmento2').val()),                                                         
        segmentos: ids,                                                                                       
        archivos: archivosProcesar                                                                            
    }                                                                                                         

    if (!validarProcentajes() & !validarSeleccionados(ids)) {                                                 
        $.ajax({                                                                                              
            data: data,                                                                                       
            url: urlAplicarFrag,                                                                              
            type: 'POST',                                                                                     
            processData: false,                                                                               
            beforeSend: function () {                                                                         
                //$("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");                                    
            },                                                                                                
            success: function (data) {                                                                        
                onSuccessAplicarFragmentacion(data);                                                          
            },                                                                                                
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {                                                
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText);                                                              
                onError(jqXHR.responseText);                                                                  
            }                                                                                                 
        });                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                         
}
```

Controller.cs

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AplicarFragmentacion(decimal fragmento1, decimal fragmento2, string[] segment\
os, HttpPostedFileBase[] archivos)                                                                            
{                                                                                                             
    List<Credito> lstSegmentos = new List<Credito>();                                                         
    try                                                                                                       
        {                                                                                                     
            ProgressHub.SendMessage("Iniciando proceso de fragmentación...", 10);                             
            lstSegmentos = await FragmentacionNegocio.AplicarFragmentacion(fragmento1, fragmento2, segmentos)\
;                                                                                                             
        }                                                                                                     
    catch (Exception ex)                                                                                      
        {                                                                                                     
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);                                                                  
        }                                                                                                     

    return Json(lstSegmentos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                                                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try submitting a FormData object, not an anonymous object with a FormData field. Also it is my understanding that the contentType should be set to false.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fragmento1', parseInt($('#fragmento1').val());
formData.append('fragmento2', parseInt($('#fragmento2').val());
formData.append('segmentos', obtenerAfiliadosSeleccionados());
formData.append('archivos', $('#fileupload')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      url: urlAplicarFrag,
      type: 'POST',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      [...]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have in my controller this parameter: HttpPostedFileBase formData. I have tried in array way and in one single object way. But still it is null.  :(

Comment: Is archivos actually an array of file uploads? Does it work if you only submit a single file upload? 

public async Task<ActionResult> AplicarFragmentacion(decimal fragmento1, decimal fragmento2, string[] segmentos, HttpPostedFileBase archivos)

Comment: https://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/ suggests you can use IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> but trying 1 file would be a good place to start. Also, does it work if you use a normal <form> submit without jquery?

Comment: Thanks, i could fix it with this plugin https://jquery-form.github.io/form/ ... easy to use. As another normal plug in, with options and callbacks

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to use this plug in

https://jquery-form.github.io/form/

In this way

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
                url: urlAplicarFrag,
                data: {
                    fragmento1: parseInt($('#fragmento1').val()),
                    fragmento2: parseInt($('#fragmento2').val()),
                    segmentos: ids,
                    fechaReenvio: $('#fecha-reenvio').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    onSuccessAplicarFragmentacion(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                    onError(jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            });
```

check the plugin website